# G Grandparents brickwall - Kilkenny/Charles and Sweeney//Magovern

Tags: records, ireland

On both sides of my father's line, I have hit brick walls.

I have not learned much information about these grandparents, nor do I know about any of their parents.

Here s what I have:

**Anthony Kilkenny and Anne Charles**. I think Anthony and Anne were born around 1830 and married ca1850-60 in Ireland.  They had about 8 children. I know information about these children.

**Bernard Sweeney and Mary McGovern/Ma Govern**. I think they were born about the same time, also in Ireland.

Any help would be apprecated.

Comment: Welcome to the site, user302. We are all working together to learn how to write great questions for the new Q&A format. As written, you question concerns the identity of as many as twelve different individuals from a base of very little information. Consider focusing on one problem or individual at a time.

Comment: I assume that like most of us tracking Irish roots you are not resident in Ireland. Are you in Australia or North America? It will help to know when the migration took place and who it was that left.

Comment: @Duncan, we should take this discussion to meta.

Answer (score 6):

Anthony was born in Mohill, Leitrim in 1829, and died there in 1900.

No marriage turns up for the couple in Leitrim. However, the baptisms of their children do turn up.

Bernard Sweeney and Mary McGovern married in 1849, in Co. Leitrim.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Brendan. Consider adding your professional association and website to your Genealogy.SE profile. If you accessed particular collections to develop this seemingly _very_ helpful information, please add those references to your answer.

Comment: Extending my comment above about adding professional credentials and your website to your profile: Your signature will probably be edited out. Here's link to the meta discussion that opens, "Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts, or they will be removed." http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures